# doesnt work rtsp stream gstreamer in opencv c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

Using gstreamer on the jetson nano board, I display rtsp stream,
My pipe on terminal is as follows:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location='rtsp://user:password...' sync=false latency=5 ! decodebin ! nvvidconv ! xvimagesink
```

And everything is fine.

I installed opencv from source and compiled it with cuda nad gstreamer capabilities, but when I run it in the following code snippet, the camera does not load:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("rtspsrc location=rtsp://user:password... sync=false latency=5 ! decodebin ! nvvidconv ! xvimagesink",cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

error is :

```
[WARN:0] global /home/kamiz/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (944) 
open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline 
[WARN:0] global /home/kamiz/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (597)
isPiplelinePlaying Opencv | GStreamer warning: pipeline have not been created 
ERROR: unable to open camera 
nvdc: start nvdcEventThread
nvdc: exit nvdcEventThread
```

This is while I display the usb camera in opencv with gstreamer without any problems.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What is xvimagesink? afair you will need to convert to BGR and nvvidconv maybe only supports RGB? And according to the error message you need an appsink ;)

Comment: https://answers.opencv.org/question/119583/how-does-the-cv2videocapture-class-work-with-gstreamer-pipelines/

Comment: Thank you for your help
But when I use appsink instead of xvimagesink I have this error: opening in BLOCKING MODE .... unable to query duration of stream ... cannot query video position: status=1 ,value=2,duration=1   ... setProperty OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unhandled property

Comment: can you try `! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink`?

Comment: hi, thank you. I did this, but I got exactly the same error as before

Comment: ok sorry, then I dont know. What's the gstreamer command with which you get the stream running in the terminal? Maybe you find more information about this error in SO or google? `opening in BLOCKING MODE .... unable to query duration of stream ... cannot query video position: status=1 ,value=2,duration=1 ... setProperty OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unhandled property`

Comment: https://github.com/TheImagingSource/tiscamera/issues/332 `encountered the exact same error and the problem turned out to be conflicting opencv installs. I had 4.3 installed on arch linux through pacman while my project was using opencv 4.2 from pip. Uninstalling 4.3 with pacman solved the issue for me.`